# triggering a pipeline from another pipeline gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to trigger a pipeline from another pipeline using '$CI_JOB_TOKEN' (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/README.html#when-used-with-multi-project-pipelines). The second pipeline is getting triggered, but it is always executing the build stage of the second pipeline. Which means it is only executing those jobs with 'except: - triggers'. I wanted to execute jobs with 'only: -triggers'

```
trigger-child-pipeline:
  stage: trigger-child-pipeline
  only:
     - triggers
  tags:
      - runner
  script:
      - curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=my_branch https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/1234/trigger/pipeline
```

I wanted to execute jobs with 'only trigger' tag in the child pipeline. Am I missing anything? I couldnt figure out anything from the documentation(https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/README.html#when-used-with-multi-project-pipelines).

Thanks

Comment: Could you share `child-pipeline` yaml? `only: -triggers` should be in child pipeline configuration, not in parent.

Comment: Yes, I have jobs with 'only: triggers' in child pipeline, these jobs are not getting triggered instead of jobs with 'except: triggers' are getting triggered.

Comment: Share both parent and child job configuration. It doesn't make sense that job with `except: triggers` runs when launched with trigger.

Comment: This child pipeline is working as expected when I trigger it directly - jobs with 'only: triggers' are getting triggered

Comment: In fact If I am triggering the child pipeline with the same code '      - curl --request POST --form "token=<trigger-token>" --form "ref=my_branch" https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/1234/trigger/pipeline, with trigger token it is working as expected.
'

Answer (score 2):

Try again with [GitLab 13.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/09/22/gitlab-13-4-released/#child-pipelines-can-now-trigger-their-own-child-pipelines) (September 2020)

You can check if its latest feature will make your use-case easier, with a different approach:

> ### Child pipelines can now trigger their own child pipelines
>
> When using parent/child pipelines, it is now possible for child pipelines to trigger
> their own child pipelines. This added depth can be useful when you want the flexibility
> to generate a variable number of child pipelines.
>
> Before, with a parent/child configuration, every child pipeline needed a trigger
> job manually defined in the parent.
>
> Now you can generate child pipelines that dynamically
> trigger any number of new child pipelines. If you have a monorepo, for example, you
> can dynamically generate a first child pipeline that itself generates a variable
> number of new child pipelines, based on the changes in a branch.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_4/parent_child_pipeline.png -- Child pipelines can now trigger their own child pipelines]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29651).

Comment: Is it also possible to use this with multi-project pipelines?

Comment: @ddsultan I don't think so, considering the documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html) mentions: "**Similarly to multi-project pipelines**, a pipeline can trigger a set of concurrently running child pipelines, but within the same project:"

Comment: Thanks. I thought so but checked myself job succeeds but trigger is not done. I used trigger API instead of YML